# Use HC05 and FTDI as Slave to Connect to control PC using HC05

Tags: hc-05, arduino-pro-micro, ftdi

Hi i just wanna ask if its possible to do this on HC05. So i can send some keyboard function?

[image]

and if yes can you tell me how. Thanks

Comment: "send some keyboard function?" - I guess you mean, that it should act as a keyboard on your PC. Thats not possible with an FTDI. It will only give you a Serial interface. But you could exchange the FTDI with an Arduino, that has a native USB interface, like the Micro (it can act as a HID device). Then you can program the micro to read data over Serial from the HC-05 and translate that to keyboard presses on the PC.

Comment: ok so i can do this with pro micro connecting to slave HC05?

Comment: Sure, if you program it to do this

Comment: Thanks. Now i have idea on what to do. Im noob sorry.